# Laravel Using Collections to group duplicate table entries

Tags: php, mysql, collections, laravel-5, group-by

Ok, so I'm trying to get the syntax for using collections. The laravel documentation and examples just make no sense to me right now. No-one's really talking about collections so:

I have two table entries, one for regions and one for countries. I'd like to be able to do something like group countries by region, so there's no printing of the duplicate regions. In php it makes sense. But in laravel, I don't get how their syntax works.

I'd like to get something like this:

Region A

- Country A
- Country B
- Country C

Region A

- Country A
- Country B

etc etc

So how's it done?

This is my controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;

class SortController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $infos = DB::table('list_countries')
            ->select('Region', 'Country')
            ->groupBy('Region')
            ->get();

       // $sorts = DB::table('list_countries')->get();
        return view('Sort', compact('infos'));
    }
}
```

This is my threadbare blade file:

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')
    <h1>Hello</h1>
                @extends('layout')


@section('content')
    <h1>Hello</h1>
                @foreach($infos as $sort)

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            {!! Form::checkbox('agree', 'yes') !!} {{ $sort }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
@stop
```

Testing @Ray Cheng's advice works:

However it prints this:

[{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Algeria"},{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Egypt"},{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Libya"},{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Mali"},{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Mauritania"},{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Morocco"},{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Niger"},{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Tunisia"},{"Region":"Africa - North Africa","Country":"Western Sahara"}]

Note that this is one category, the groupby is working, but it's including the objects it's grouping by.

The database table looks like this:

[image: Database tables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is use collection function `groupBy`:

```
$infos = DB::table('list_countries')
        ->select('Region', 'Country')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('Region')
        ->toArray();
```

Comment: This does indeed work! But the array to the view doesn't make the region a unique instance, it just groups it (well duh that's what it's called.) but I was under the impression a groupBy will print a single instance and the items attached to it. 
Also, how do I call the array elements in blade now? {{ $info->Region }} gives me an error.

Comment: @mugluck you better attach results to me, or i can't know what's wrong with you results

Comment: Edited the main post to show your request. @Ray Cheng

Comment: @Mugluck, it's a json datas, you should add `toArray()` to the end of groupBy

Comment: This throws an array error. How do I convert the blade file? "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given..."

Comment: @Mugluck,i'm not quiet sure what's wrong with your code, that is a json datas printed. use `dd` function to test the result, i believe you can fix it,